# Syntax of Range Selection with input from user

Tags: vba, excel, range, user-input

Here is my code.  I am trying to copy the two raws from different sheets and paste them in another sheet.  The selection is made by the user by entering the number of raw which wants to graphic.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
 - 

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
Dim Date1 As Variant 
Date1 = InputBox("Cell number you want to graph.  Enter any cell number from
       4 to 863", "Cell Number")

   Sheets("Deflection").Select
       *******Range("E  & "Date1":DG & "Date1" ").Select*******
       Selection.Copy
       Sheets("Static Rate Curve").Select
       Range("A2").Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
           False, Transpose:=True
       Sheets("Load").Select
       **Range("E  & "Date1":DG & "Date1" ").Select**
       Selection.Copy
       Sheets("Static Rate Curve").Select
       Range("B2").Select`enter code here`
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
           False, Transpose:=True
       Range("D8").Select
```

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting. String literals are red. Where are the `&` concatenation operators? Inside or outside the strings? You mean to do `Range("E" & ...` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wsSource1 As Worksheet, wsSource2 As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim Date1 As Variant

Set wsSource1 = Sheets("Deflection")
Set wsSource2 = Sheets("Load")
Set wsDest = Sheets("Static Rate Curve")

Date1 = InputBox("Cell number you want to graph. Enter any cell number from 4 to 863", "Cell Number")

wsSource1.Range("E" & Date1 & ":DG" & Date1).Copy
wsDest.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True

wsSource2.Range("E" & Date1 & ":DG" & Date1).Copy
wsDest.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Sktneer. This resolved my problem.  I got it now.

Comment: You're welcome Alfonso! Glad it worked. Please take a moment to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.